# export 60GB large sql Table Data into csv file as back up with Python

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have sql table which has 60+GB of Data. I would like to save into csv file as backup.
I am using below method. this method is working but taking 4-5 hours.
I want all records with header , and compress csv files at end.

thanks in advance for help.

Is there a faster way than this approach. i was using this approach.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

    # Open the file
    f = open('output.csv', 'w')
    # Create a connection and get a cursor
    connection = pyodbc.connect('SQL SERVER') # ....
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Execute the query
    cursor.execute('select * from mydata')
    # Get data in batches
    while True:
        # Read the data
        df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
        # We are done if there are no data
        if len(df) == 0:
            break
        # Let's write to the file
        else:
            df.to_csv(f, header=False)
    
    # Clean up
    f.close()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I suggest using SQL Server itself, follow this [guide](https://blog.devart.com/how-to-export-sql-server-data-from-table-to-a-csv-file.html) sadly there is no code that i can provide

Comment: Why ńot simoly back up the whole db? Otherwise in case of Postgres, there is the possibility to export a table as CSV by https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: That is one good method , which is faster one compared to python. I have 128gb ram. still slow , few colleagues told pandas is slower and I am using it,  I want to do it via coding and it will learning exercise also. thanks for help.

Comment: Quary = "select * from Table1"
x = 0
With open("E:\\backup\\output.csv","w","newline="") as outfile
 writer = csv.writer(outfile,quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
 writer.writerows(col[0] for col in cursor.description)
 While True:
  rows = cursor.fetchmany(10000)
  if len(rows) ==0:
   print("no records found")
   break
  else:
           x = x+len(rows)
               print(x)
               for row in rows:
                  writer.writerows(row)
conn.close()
print("success")
print('time taken' . time.time()-initial,"Seconds")